# In which freebsd release libdl.so sys calls are included in libc.so?

Tags: freebsd, libc

Currently I am facing issue with running python3.6 , bash and many other on my FreeBSD box, As a workaround we have a created a symlink for libdl.so => libc.so and it works but we would like to know more about it.

Comment: X/Y problem. You should start figuring why python3.6 wasn't working out of the box in first place.

Comment: Does the python binary match the OS version?  Did you upgrade the server from say 10.x to 11.x or anything like that?  I'd reinstall the python package.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your running an unsupported version of freebsd (11.1) and have recently updated python using pkg. In 11.2, FreeBSD began providing libdl.so, and the build in pkg now probably has been compiled against libdl or with the --ldl switch... Since the library isn't installed in 11.1 by default (you could copy it from 11.2 release) python will not run..... Either update to 11.2 or see if pull the base.tgz from a mirror and extract libdl.so.1 from it.

Good luck...